# Do not allow users to create new posts and pages

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

I'm defining a new user role called `Proofreader` and as the name says, users of this group should be able to read and also edit the posts and pages. But I do not want them to create new ones.

With my custom post types I can set a capability `create_post -> create_{cpt_name}` and set it to false for this user group. In the backend they now don't see the add button, but can still edit the posts. That's exactly what I want. Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to set this capability for the predefined CPT of WordPress (Posts & Pages). Also the [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin seems to be unable to restrict user roles of creating new posts while letting them edit.

While researching, I found, that this seems to be a big issue of WordPress which is not solved yet. Is this true?

If not, I would be really thankful if anyone could help me out with this... It would really be a solution of a big problem of my website!

Answer (score 0):

Use remove_cap for this.

```
function remove_proofreader_create_posts(){
    global $wp_roles;
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'proof_reader', 'create_posts' );
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'proof_reader', 'create_pages' );
}
```

NOTE: This is not a global function, but a method of the WP_Roles, WP_Role and WP_User classes. It must be called using an instance of one of these classes, as shown in the examples.

ALSO: You'll want to call the function once, as in during plugin activation, not on a constant hook.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I was busy... I don't know why, but it does not work...

Comment: Did you add the function with an add action?

Comment: Yes of course. For testing reasons I added it on `init`

Comment: Just to check, that none of the proofreaders are also editors or something else that has the capability.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this alternate approach to remove_cap() will do the trick

```
add_action( 'init', 'stackx_set_proof_reader_capabilities' );
function stackx_set_proof_reader_capabilities() {

   // Get the role object.
   $role = get_role( 'proof_reader' );

   // A list of capabilities to remove from editors.
   $caps = array(
       'creat_posts',
       'create_pages',
   );

   foreach ( $caps as $cap ) :
       // Remove the capability.
       $role->remove_cap( $cap );
   endforeach;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either :( Are you sure, that it's possible to remove that capability for the built in post types? When registering a CPT, you can add the `create_posts` cap and set it to `create_{cpt_name}`. That works well in my case, but this seems to be ignored...

Comment: I cannot say that I have ever removed this specific set before, but I can't think of any reason it shouldn't go like any other. I will spin up a test site this evening and confirm.